# How to get the details of user who is downloading a file from my webpage before downloading it?

Tags: forms, email, download

How to get the details of user who is downloading a file from my webpage before downloading it?

Its easy to download a file from webpage and i simply do it with a href tag but what i want is, get the user info like name, email address to my mail before he/she downloads the file. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use some server side technology such as PHP, you could build an HTML form asking for all the data you'd like to gather about the user and then submit to your PHP script.

Your PHP script could store that data inside a DB and then serve the file the user is interested in by using some script like this one:

There is even an example of this on php.net

```
<?php
   // We'll be outputting a PDF
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');

   // It will be called downloaded.pdf
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

  // The PDF source is in original.pdf
  readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

You could even decide whether you allow to download the file or not improving your code with something like this:

```
<?php
    if ( can_this_file_be_downloaded() ) {
      header('Content-type: application/pdf');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"');
      readfile("{$_GET['filename']}.pdf");
    } else {
      die("None shall pass");
    }
 ?>
```

**Edit**
If you have more than one file, a very basic approach without the support of a DB would be to setup every download file link to something like: download.php?id=1, download.php?id=2, and so on.

Then in your PHP, to decide which file the user wants to download:

```
 <?php
   switch($_GET['id'])
   {
     case 1:
      $filename = "my_file_1.pdf";
      break;
     case 2:
      $filename = "some_file.pdf";
      break;

      ...
   }

   readfile($filename);
 ?>
```

Comment: thank you so much @rrr but now i don't want to store it in DB. Instead am using PHP for mailing the form data to my mail using the following code.

Comment: <?php
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['comments'])){

$first_name= $_POST['first_name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$mobile= $_POST['mobile'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$comments= $_POST['comments'];

if (!empty($first_name) && !empty($address)){
 $to = 'rameshjoe381@gmail.com';
 $subject = 'Contact Form Submitted.';
 $body = "Name: ".$first_name."\n\n"."Address: ".$address."\n\n"."Mobile: ".$mobile."\n\n"."Phone No: ".$phone."\n\n"."Message: ".$comments;
 $headers = 'From: '.$email;

Comment: how can i do without storing in database

Comment: It's pretty much the same, below your code to mail the user info data, just serve the file the user wants to download with the script I posted. The script must act as a proxy.

Comment: thank you so much again @rrr if you don't mind. i have 10 different files to be downloaded from my page. if the user clicks any one of it,   the popup window ll show a html form to be filled by user. after proper submission of the form that particular file has to be downloaded. 
now my question is, i can do this for one file with the code given by you. what can i do for 10files?

Comment: Answer updated with a very basic solution of how you could do that for more than one file.

Comment: I Copied that code. but it is not downloading. but the mail function works perfectly. 
    <?php
   // We'll be outputting a PDF
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');

   // It will be called downloaded.pdf
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

  // The PDF source is in original.pdf
  readfile('original.pdf');
?>  is this code s enough for downloading

Comment: what should i type in the place of downloaded.pdf and original.pdf

Comment: I've just tested and the code is working, you should type the name of the file to download, making sure it exists and it's correctly located.

Comment: i dont know where i made mistake but it is not downloading the file. i guess it fails to open. can you insert the code it within my code? i dnt knw whether i can send screenshot here

Answer (score 1):

if download is provided to only registered users you can get this stuff from database via user id or user name, otherwise you have to ask them to put these details in text fields.

if you want other details like ip address, browser version etc you can eaisly get it by calling [This link](http://ifconfig.me/all.json)

Comment: we dont have login register in our site. all we need is just few information like name, phone number. which can be get from a form and mailed using php. once the user filled the form.. particular file can be downloaded. how to do that?